# How do I disable <Control><Alt>S to allow myself to launch Sublime?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, sublime-text

I've been using Sublime Text 2 quit a bit lately and want to make it as easy to launch as Terminal.

I've done the following so far:

1. I went into System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows and disabled the shortcut for Toggled Shaded (Ctrl + Alt + S).
2. I used gconf-editor to add <Control><Primary><Alt>S under apps/metacity/global_keybindings/run_command_1 and pointed it to /usr/bin/sublime under apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/command_1.
3. I went into dconf-editor and changed the Toggle Shadows shortcut to <Control><Super>S under org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings.

I am still unable to launch Sublime with the shortcut Ctrl + Alt + S, and normal windows still keep being toggled with the shortcut. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I went back into System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows and changed the shortcut for Toggled Shaded to Ctrl + Super + S. Now Ctrl + Super + S causes a toggle state, but Ctrl + Alt + S doesnt do anything. 

I am not sure if this has something to do with the location I put in gconf-editor. I ran the "which sublime" command, which gave me "/usr/bin/sublime" as the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by going into the Shortcuts settings of Ubuntu (`System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`) and simply creating a custom shortcut with the command /usr/bin/sublime, then double click on the "Disabled" area and pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> keys.

Changing anything in gconf-editor under both user & root access didn't change a thing.

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldn't figure out why an options dialog in Qt Creator was closing whenever I used Ctrl + Alt + S... I set "Toggle shaded state" to Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is going on without a deep study of your configuration.  BUT try using gconf-editor to look at /apps/metacity/window_keybindings for "toggle_shaded". That generally is set to Ctrl+Alt+S.  If you're not using the metacity window manager then this change will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked like as in the [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1113863/951943) , but within a different record

```
$ sudo apt install dconf-editor
$ dconf-editor /org/gnome/shell/extensions/screenshot-window-sizer/cycle-screenshot-sizes
```

> Turn off the "Use default value" toggle. Then replace the "Custom value" field with []. Then click the blue checkbox (save button) and close the window.