# How to disable Ctrl+Alt+S in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

I couldn't find anything in Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, nothing that said `Ctrl+Alt+S` or `Toggle shaded state` as many other answers pointed out.

How do I disable the default action for `Ctrl+Alt+S` in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal, and run the following command:

```
dconf-editor /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-shaded
```

Turn off the "Use default value" toggle. Then replace the "Custom value" field with `[]`. Then click the blue checkbox (save button) and close the window.

Answer (score 3):

For me worked like the [answer Sumit gave](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113864/106495), but within a different record

```
$ sudo apt install dconf-editor
$ dconf-editor /org/gnome/shell/extensions/screenshot-window-sizer/cycle-screenshot-sizes
```

> Turn off the "Use default value" toggle. Then replace the "Custom value" field with []. Then click the blue checkbox (save button) and close the window.